# Given $2$ ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, how to contruct an ordinal contains them as elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, constructive-mathematics

Suppose $\alpha, \beta$ are ordinals, as ordinals are sets of ordinals, it seems that it is possible to construct an ordinal that contains $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as elements.

I am not able to construct such an ordinal so far. If it is possible, could someone give an explicit construction with justification? Thanks so much!

**definition of ordinal:**

transitive:  $x ⊆ S$ for every $x ∈ S$.

A total order $≤$ on a set S is said to be a well-ordering if for every non-empty subset $A ⊆ S$, there exists an element $m ∈ A$ such that $ ∀x ∈ A,m\le x$

An ordinal number is a set that is transitive and is well-ordered by the relation
$α ≤ β ⇔ α ∈ β \lor α = β. $

Answer (score 4):

Ordinals are transitive sets, so $\alpha \in \gamma$ is equivalent to $\alpha \subsetneq \gamma$. So take their union, and show it's an ordinal. Then take the successor.

That a union of ordinals (in your definition) is an ordinal can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135331/4280). So $\gamma:=\alpha \cup \beta$ is an ordinal, such that $\alpha \subseteq  \gamma$ and $\beta \subseteq \gamma$. To ensure that $\alpha \in \delta$ we need $\alpha \subsetneq \delta$, so define $\delta = \gamma + 1 =\gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ and this contains $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as elements.

Comment: Sorry but so far I cannot see why $\alpha\subseteq \gamma\Rightarrow \alpha\in \gamma$, which is a direction of "equivalent".

Comment: @Y.X. The proof will depend on the exact definition of ordinal you're using

Comment: @Could you please look at the edited question where I give a definition?

Comment: @Y.X. Successor of union is still my answer

Comment: @Y.X. note that it's "is a strict subset", not "is a subset"

Comment: That is, $\alpha, \gamma$ ordinals satisfy $\alpha \subseteq \gamma \implies (\alpha \in \gamma \lor \alpha = \gamma)$.